# How to remove "non-existent' file from an APFS directory?

Tags: terminal, permission, macos

About midnight, I closed my MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), which puts it to sleep.  The only apps open were TextEdit and Finder (as far as the Dock shows).  Nothing was in the Trash (according to the Dock icon).  All software is up-to-date including macOS 12.1 (21C52).

When I opened it the next morning, the Trash icon showed not-empty.  Looking inside, I saw a folder called `Recovered files`.  Now, these have often appeared in the past, but they have always been in either ~/Desktop or /Users/Shared.  They have never contained anything worth keeping (usually a soft link to a path that doesn't exist).  I've always just deleted them and moved on.  This is the first time one of these (or anything else) has apparently moved into the Trash while the laptop was asleep.

When I tried to empty trash, it was not allowed "because xxx is in use."  I've forgotten whether xxx is `Recovered files` or the file inside which was named `knowledge-ag%nt.plist.CQbdANk`.  It was a regular file, not a symlink.

I moved `Recovered files` to /tmp, closed the Trash, exited all apps, and even Re-launched Finder, then shut down.  Normally, startup removes almost anything in /tmp.  But this time, `Recovered files` is still in /tmp.  The file inside had an xattr of com.apple.macl, which is allegedly not removable, but

Update: I typed a couple of paragraphs after that dangling half-sentence and saw them after saving.  Don't know where they went.  Anyway, I am going to try First Aid on the internal SSD and see if it clears that.  It's not important enough for Recovery mode by itself, but now Time Machine is being weird, so that motivates me  bit more.

Comment: Also, neither "Recovery" nor "CQbdANk" can be found in the output of `lsof`.

Comment: I noticed a similar behavior after applying the latest Monterey 12.2.1 security bundle. In my case, `/Users/Shared` contained the `Relocated Items` following the installation and the previous `Relocated Items` was assigned to `Previously Relocated...` as I would expect. There was also a `Relocated Items` in the trash which I haven't seen before. Without much thought, I simply (successfully) emptied the trash, having noted the expected contents in `/Users/Shared`.

Comment: Interesting.  I've seen them after every update, and occasionally at other times.  But never in the Trash till today.

Comment: Unfortunately, for reasons unknown, half of what I typed is missing from the question.  It was there when I clicked "Post"