# File in Trash cannot be deleted, not even with sudo rm

Tags: terminal, mac, monterey, trash, dropbox

Ever since Dropbox updated its software a few months ago, and advised all Mac users to update in order to continue having the same facilities, a folder in my Dropbox Cloud was apparently corrupted and could not be read. I tried to salvage what I could and deleted the folder directly from the Dropbox site. It, however, appears in my Trash and cannot be deleted. I get: "The operation can't be completed because the item <> is in use". (All other items do get deleted from Trash.)
I have tried sudo rm commands from Terminal, using all possible parameters (-R, -ri, -rf etc.) to no avail. I have tried to erase it *before* Dropbox gets loaded at startup, again to no avail. I have erased ".Trash", but again the stubborn file pops up in the Trash.
I am using MacOS Monterey 12.6.6 on a Mac Pro (Late 2013). Help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `sudo fs_usage | grep [path_to_folder]` in order to ensure that Dropbox is the only process which is using the folder ? It could be another process. Alternatively did you try rebooting in safe mode to make the operation of emptying the trash ?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Rebooting in safe mode did not help. I have just tried your sudo fs_usage suggestion and I get the following response that I cannot understand: 20:46:25  getattrlist       /Users/enahmad/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/.Trash/España                      0.000018   fileprovider
20:46:25  open              /Users/enahmad/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/.Trash/España                      0.000034   fileprovider
20:46:25  openat            [-2]//Users/enahmad/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/.Trash/España                 0.000011   fileprovider
What should I do?

Comment: with that response you can know fileprovider is a process that uses some files inside .Trash. Perhaps trying to force quit these processes would help. But this process is a system process, that is probably launched by a master process

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/445235/65467).  The solution was to move the item to `/tmp` and reboot.  (Reboot deletes everything in `/tmp`)